# How to tell if ID is a Facebook App or User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page that is using Open Graph and FBML to put a Like and Send button on my page. The client has provided me with two "User IDs" per my request; however, when I submit them in the fb:admins meta tag and use it against the Facebook debug, I get the following error `Too many app ids specified`, despite not providing a fb:app_id meta tag.

My question is simple, how do I determine whether an ID provided is a user ID or an app ID?

Comment: Try adding them to the Facebook graph URL and check the results: `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=XXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY` where `XXXXXXX` and `YYYYYYYY` are the IDs.

Comment: That seems to do it, given that what appear to be apps don't come back with anything. Post an answer and I'll give it the credit it deserves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding them to the Facebook graph URL and check the results: `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=XXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY` where `XXXXXXX` and `YYYYYYYY` are the IDs, example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=579187142,40796308305
```

Querying my ID and Coca-Cola's page id would return:

```
{
   "579187142": {
      "id": "579187142",
      "name": "Ibrahim Faour",
      "first_name": "Ibrahim",
      "last_name": "Faour",
      "username": "ifaour",
      "gender": "male",
      "locale": "en_US"
   },
   "40796308305": {
      "id": "40796308305",
      "name": "Coca-Cola",
      "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203509_40796308305_256509_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
      "likes": 33623022,
      "category": "Food/beverages",
      "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
      "username": "coca-cola",
      "founded": "1886",
      "products": "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in history, as well as the best-known product in the world.\n\nCreated in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. Coca-Cola was introduced in 1886, patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States.\n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.",
      "parking": {
         "street": 0,
         "lot": 0,
         "valet": 0
      },
      "hours": {
         "mon_1_open": 0,
         "mon_1_close": 0,
         "tue_1_open": 0,
         "tue_1_close": 0,
         "wed_1_open": 0,
         "wed_1_close": 0,
         "thu_1_open": 0,
         "thu_1_close": 0,
         "fri_1_open": 0,
         "fri_1_close": 0,
         "sat_1_open": 0,
         "sat_1_close": 0,
         "sun_1_open": 0,
         "sun_1_close": 0,
         "mon_2_open": 0,
         "mon_2_close": 0,
         "tue_2_open": 0,
         "tue_2_close": 0,
         "wed_2_open": 0,
         "wed_2_close": 0,
         "thu_2_open": 0,
         "thu_2_close": 0,
         "fri_2_open": 0,
         "fri_2_close": 0,
         "sat_2_open": 0,
         "sat_2_close": 0,
         "sun_2_open": 0,
         "sun_2_close": 0
      },
      "payment_options": {
         "cash_only": 0,
         "visa": 0,
         "amex": 0,
         "mastercard": 0,
         "discover": 0
      },
      "restaurant_services": {
         "reserve": 0,
         "walkins": 0,
         "groups": 0,
         "kids": 0,
         "takeout": 0,
         "delivery": 0,
         "catering": 0,
         "waiter": 0,
         "outdoor": 0
      },
      "restaurant_specialties": {
         "breakfast": 0,
         "lunch": 0,
         "dinner": 0,
         "coffee": 0,
         "drinks": 0
      }
   }
}
```

And query a single id:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=291549705119
```

Which is CityVille App:

```
{
   "id": "291549705119",
   "name": "CityVille",
   "description": "Grab your hard hats and work boots, 'cause it's time to get building! Welcome to CityVille, where you and your friends can build the city of your dreams!  Play now at: http://zyn.ga/1qJ",
   "category": "Games",
   "subcategory": "Other",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=291549705119"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

another way is to query the obj ID with a param metadata=1,

e.g. query 123213121232131229?metadata=1&fields=id

in the returned metadata, check for the value in "type" field